# Deserialize object in Json response to array C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, serialization, json.net

Currently I'm writing a mobile app with Xamarin.Forms and my problem is, that I need the response from my API in separate variables instead of one string output.

My API output:

```
{"error":false,"user":{"id":3,"email":"root@root.de","vorname":"root","nachname":"toor","wka":"wka1"}}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft to deserialize the response and I think that the problem is the curly bracket behind `"user":{...}` because I can print out `public bool error { get; set; }` but the other vars are not working.

```
class JsonContent
    {
        public bool error { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string vorname { get; set; }
        public string nachname { get; set; }
        public string wka { get; set; }
    }
```

Tests:

```
JsonContent j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonContent>(response.Content);
bool pout = j.error;  //output: false

JsonContent j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonContent>(response.Content);
int pout = j.id;  //output: 0
```

Comment: The class is wrong.  Copy the JSON to the clipboard and use **Edit Menu** > **Paste Special** > **Paste JSON as classes**.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: user is an object within the response, and id is a property of the user object, not the base response object.  Use a tool like http://json2csharp.com to help generate the proper C# classes for your data

Comment: there are only 2 properties, error:bool and a dictionary<string,string" called "user" on the datamodel so adjust your class

Comment: The solution with json2csharp.com is working, thanks to the fast response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some json to c# converter to get the model, i.e. https://jsonutils.com , http://json2csharp.com. It will help you when you have to get the model of a big json.

```
public class User
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string email { get; set; }
   public string vorname { get; set; }
   public string nachname { get; set; }
   public string wka { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public bool error { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The C# class that you have for your JSON is not correct.

It should be

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string vorname { get; set; }
    public string nachname { get; set; }
    public string wka { get; set; }
}

public class JsonContent
{
    public bool error { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can deserialize your JSON to your C# objects